# How to pad or add leading zeros to months

Tags: applescript

How do I pad or add leading zeros to months? For example, May would return "05"

```
set the_month_new to button returned of (display dialog "Choose a month:" buttons {"April", "May", "June"})

(run script the_month_new) as integer
```

Comment: Is that really how you are getting the months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
set the_month_new to button returned of (display dialog "Choose a month:" buttons {"April", "May", "December"})

set the_month to (run script the_month_new) as integer

if the_month is less than 10 then
    set the_month to "0" & the_month
else
    set the_month to the_month as string
end if
```